# Is there a word or phrase for someone who asks for help, but wants you to do everything?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Maybe my definition of help is skewed, but to me it means cooperation to meet a goal, or some element of teamwork.
But is there a word or phrase for the action of (or the person) asking for help, but in reality wanting you to do the whole thing for them?

Comment: Sounds like they are asking for favor.

Answer (score 2):

You could call him a *moocher*.

> **Moocher (noun):** one who exploits the generosity of others : a person who [mooches](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mooch#h1) off others.
>
> [[Merriam-Webster]](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/moocher)

(*[Shiftless](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/shiftless)* or *[indolent](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/indolent)* could also be used.)